# Can I use OSGi Mocks with Declarative Services Annotations

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit, osgi, aem

I'm trying to test an OSGi service annodated with Declaratice Services annotations (`org.osgi.service.component.annotations`). I have generated my project based on the [AEM Multi-Project Example](https://github.com/Cognifide/gradle-aem-multi).

```
public class PostServiceTest {

  @Rule
  public AemContext context = new AemContext((AemContextCallback) context -> {
    context.registerInjectActivateService(new PostService());
  }, ResourceResolverType.RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK);

  @Test
  public void shouldFetchRandomPosts() {
    final PostService postsService = context.getService(PostService.class);
    final List<Post> posts = postsService.randomPosts(100);

    assertEquals(100, posts.size());
  }

}
```

Whenever I run this test in IntelliJ, OSGi Mocks complain about hte absence of SCR metadata on the tested class.

```
org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.NoScrMetadataException: No OSGi SCR metadata found for class com.example.PostServiceTest
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.OsgiServiceUtil.injectServices(OsgiServiceUtil.java:381)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockOsgi.injectServices(MockOsgi.java:148)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.OsgiContextImpl.registerInjectActivateService(OsgiContextImpl.java:153)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.OsgiContextImpl.registerInjectActivateService(OsgiContextImpl.java:168)
  at com.example.PostServiceTest.shouldReturnTheEnpointNamesWithValidConfigurationAsTheListOfAcceptableKeys(PostServiceTest.java:23)
```

Does this mean I can only test classes annotated with the older SCR annotations that come with Apache Felix? The documentation for OSGi Mocks [suggests that Declarative Services annotations is supported in version 2.0.0 and higher](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/osgi-mock.html). The version I'm using meets this criterion.

Comment: If you use the BND plugin with Gradle this might help you (you have to adapt it for Gradle): http://felix.apache.org/documentation/faqs/apache-felix-bundle-plugin-faq.html#use-scr-metadata-generated-by-bnd-in-unit-tests

Comment: @Jens the Gradle plugin does generate the metadata. My issue stemmed from the fact that the IDE would not do this when compiling the sources for tests. Delegating the compilation to Gradle did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, this only happened when I ran the test directly form the IDE. It turns out that IntelliJ was not generating the SCR metadata when compiling my classes for tests.

When I compile the class under test with Gradle, the `'com.cognifide.aem.bundle'` plugin is used to generate the SCR descriptor and place it in the resulting Java Archive. That's why unit tests executed by Gradle work fine. Just clicking the *Run* button in IntelliJ caused this step to be missed.

In order to get this working, I ended up setting up IntelliJ to allow me to run unit tests via Gradle.

I went to *Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Runner* and used the dropdown menu so that I could decide whether to use Gradle on a test-by-test basis.

[image: Settings dialog in IntelliJ with a checkbox that says 'Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle' and a dropdown menu with the option 'Let me choos per test' selected]